# how to extends es6 class using Dojo

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, dojo

I have some es6 class

```
class Human {
    constructor(){
         this.age = 0;
    }
}
```

I want to inherit from this class using dojo toolkit

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"],
function (declare) {
    return declare("Man", Human, {
    });
});
```

I'm getting the error `Class constructor Human cannot be invoked without 'new'`.

Tried to inherit from `Human.constructor` and from `Human.funcWrapper`

```
class Human {
    constructor(){
         this.age = 0;
    }

    static funcWrapper(){
         return new Human()
    }
}
```

Nothing worked.

I know that I can use babel to transform my code to functions but I don't want because of some political reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, i'm posting banging my head for hours, and then i'm coming with a solution. So far i've tested it, and look like it is working good. including calling `this.inherited(arguments, ["bla"])` (dojo way of calling `super("bla")`)

So, I've created this function to convert es6 class to function class

```
function funcClass(type) {
    const FuncClass = function (...args) {
        const _source = Reflect.construct(type, args, this.constructor);

        const keys = Reflect.ownKeys(_source);
        for (const key of keys) {
            if (!key.match || !key.match(/^(?:constructor|prototype|arguments|caller|name|bind|call|apply|toString|length)$/)) {
                const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_source, key);
                !this[key] && Object.defineProperty(this, key, desc);
            }
        }
    }
    FuncClass.prototype = type.prototype;

    return FuncClass;
}
```

And usage:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"],
function (declare) {
    return declare("Man", funcClass(Human), {
    });
});
```

Comment: Good work man, I was just wondering me if DojoToolkit has support for ES6 classes, With your test I know until now it doesn't